# Barcode Readings Not Uploading to Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, barcode

I want to scan the barcodes and send it to Firestore.
In the code one I have the code for barcode reading. In the second code I have the code for importing the barcodes from the first code and send to Firebase. The issue is eventhough the barcode values are imported, they are not sending to the Firestore.

In order to check the connection with the Firestore, I add two numbers in another new file and use the same second code to upload to Firestore. These values are displayed in the Firestore. Only these barcode reading values are not uploading to the firestore.

Why these barcode readings are not displayed in the firestore.

code one -Reading Barcodes

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import pyrebase
import sys

def barcode_reader():
    hid = {4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f', 10: 'g', 11: 'h', 12: 'i', 13: 'j', 14: 'k', 15: 'l', 16: 'm',
           17: 'n', 18: 'o', 19: 'p', 20: 'q', 21: 'r', 22: 's', 23: 't', 24: 'u', 25: 'v', 26: 'w', 27: 'x', 28: 'y',
           29: 'z', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '3', 33: '4', 34: '5', 35: '6', 36: '7', 37: '8', 38: '9', 39: '0', 44: ' ',
           45: '-', 46: '=', 47: '[', 48: ']', 49: '\\', 51: ';', 52: '\'', 53: '~', 54: ',', 55: '.', 56: '/'}

    hid2 = {4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'E', 9: 'F', 10: 'G', 11: 'H', 12: 'I', 13: 'J', 14: 'K', 15: 'L', 16: 'M',
            17: 'N', 18: 'O', 19: 'P', 20: 'Q', 21: 'R', 22: 'S', 23: 'T', 24: 'U', 25: 'V', 26: 'W', 27: 'X', 28: 'Y',
            29: 'Z', 30: '!', 31: '@', 32: '#', 33: '$', 34: '%', 35: '^', 36: '&', 37: '*', 38: '(', 39: ')', 44: ' ',
            45: '_', 46: '+', 47: '{', 48: '}', 49: '|', 51: ':', 52: '"', 53: '~', 54: '<', 55: '>', 56: '?'}

    fp = open('hidraw0', 'w+') 

    ss = ""
    shift = False

    done = False

    while not done:
        # Get the character from the HID
        buffer = fp.read(8)
        for c in buffer:
            if ord(c) > 0:

                #  40 is carriage return which signifies
               
                if int(ord(c)) == 40:
                    done = True
                    break;

                
                #  use the hid2 characters.
                if shift:

                    # If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
                    if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                        shift = True

                    # if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
                    else:
                        ss += hid2[int(ord(c))]
                        shift = False

                #  If not shifted then use
                #  the hid characters

                else:

                    # If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
                    if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                        shift = True

                    # if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
                    else:
                        ss += hid[int(ord(c))]
    return ss
    print (type(ss))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            barcode_reader()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

second code -  Importing data and upload to Firestore

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from barcode import barcode_reader

cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db=firestore.client()
a = barcode_reader()
#print(a)

ref= db.collection('barcodes').document()
ref.set({"barcode": a})
```

Comment: Hi @Ameesha Sheron, Can you provide a sample output of the function `barcode_reader()?` Also, do you intend to use `set` instead of `add`? If you intend to use `set`, you should put an identifier to the document e.g. `ref= db.collection('barcodes').document("document_id")`

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB the output of the function is just the barcode value. for example 765756931182

Comment: also I changed the code a bit as follows  `import firebase_admin  
from firebase_admin import credentials  
from firebase_admin import firestore  from barcode import barcode_reader  cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")  
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)  
db=firestore.client()  
a = barcode_reader()  data = {'barcode':a}  db.collection('barcodes').add(data)
`                                                                        `

Comment: Have you encountered any error messages? Have you tried to hard-code the value in your `a` variable and check if the data is uploaded to Firestore. e.g: `ref.set({"barcode": '765756931182'})`. If it works, then you have to check the output of your `barcode_reader()` function.